# History.js can't get back to an empty state

Tags: javascript, history.js

I'm working on a gallery viewer and I use History.js to get a nice link.
Here is the flow:

http://foo.com/gallery/show/ shows the main gallery

http://foo.com/gallery/show/photo1 shows the viewer with the photo

so I use History.pushState({}, "photo1") to go from show/ to show/photo1

My problem is when I close the viewer I want the url to come back to show/ so I tried:
History.pushState({}, "") but this doesn't work it just stays at show/photo1.

By the way I don't really want to use History.go(-X) has it doesn't seem logical to me in that use case.

How can I do that? 
Thank you

Comment: It would be something like: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/rAxAw/)
(I haven't checked that everything was correct in my code but the History idea is there).

When you hit an image link it should show the viewer and update the address to /imageX when I click the close link I want the address to go back to /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <a class='img' href="img1">Image 1</a>
    <a class='img' href="img2">Image 2</a>
    <div class="image-viewer" style="display:none"><p></p>
    <a class="close" href="">Close</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
​
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
var begin=location.href;
$(".img").on('click', function(e) {
    console.log(location.href);
    var href = $(this).attr("href")
    History.pushState({"state": href, "rand": Math.random()}, "", href);
        console.log(location.href);
     e.preventDefault();
});

History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function() {
    $(".image-viewer p").html(History.getState());
    $(".image-viewer").show();
});

$(".close").click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).parent());
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(1);
    History.pushState({"state": begin, "rand": Math.random()}, "", begin);
});
​})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rAxAw/2/

Feel free to ask any q-n if need futher help

Comment: This is perfect. I weirdly thought that pushing a full path would make the page refresh. Anyhow it works prefectly thanks.